# Issue with google service plugin and databinding

Tags: android, data-binding, google-play-services

I was using databinding in my project. Then I want to use Firebase so I added google service plugin in my project

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.1'
```

after this... my project cannot compile with the error:

```
Cannot change dependencies of configuration ':app:api' after it has been included in dependency resolution.
```

if I disable databinding.. or remove google service plugin, this error will be gone.

I still want to use databinding. How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 2):

Just realize this is a known issue. no solution for now.
Need to disable google service plugin for now
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79122163

Answer (score 1):

The error has disappeared after updating to

`classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'`